# Importing songs to Rocksmith 2014

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I have read that, as long as there is a save file of the original Rocksmith on the hard drive, you can import the old songs into Rocksmith 2014 with an import tool that can be bought from the PSN.

I have sometimes read that all disc songs can be imported, but on [a (German) review at 4players it says that apparently 14 songs do not import](http://www.4players.de/4players.php/procontra/Allgemein/Test/Fazit_Wertung/Allgemein/34844/80077/Rocksmith_2014_-_All-New_Edition.html).

Translation:

> Pro:
>
> - songs of the predecessor can be imported...
>
> Con:
>
> - ... but only with costs (10€) and not completely (14 songs missing)

Now the question is:
Do all songs from the original Rocksmith disc and also all DLC available for the original Rocksmith import to Rocksmith 2014 by buying the import tool, or are some songs excluded?

Comment: Are you *also* in Germany? Due to music licensing having to be negotiated per-country, it's entirely possible that what is true for transferring songs in Germany has no connection to what is true for transferring songs where you are.

Comment: yes, I live in Germany, and you could be right. I hadn't thought of that but there are often licensing problems in Germany due to the organization GEMA wanting ridiculous licensing fees. That could actually be a reason for having less songs in Germany, but I didn't find anything confirming that. I'd also guess that if there were a region specific change, it would be mentioned somewhere and result in a lower price.

Comment: Hm. The en-US FAQ says it'll import all but 5 songs (due to licensing); it makes no mention of that being different for different countries, but it may assume a US reader. I can't find a German-language FAQ anywhere. On the plus side, there appears to be no relicensing fee necessary for original-version DLC, only for original-disc songs (which is what I would expect, since licensing music for download is usually just "for download" without a platform restriction, while music licensing for disc distribution is almost always restricted to that exact disc).

Comment: I have found the German FAQ (you have to change the url to de-de), but it's shorter. It doesn't mention that 5 songs are excluded, but also doesn't confirm that all songs are included. It only says "Rocksmith 2014 is backwards compatible. You will be able to play the songs from the disc of the original Rocksmith". So it could be assumed that all songs work, but it's not really phrased precisely. But it's good news that the DLC works. Thanks for your help! (And I could have thought to have a look in the FAQ myself, searched everywhere but there :p)

Comment: Ah, that's just the exact same wording as the English FAQ had before 2014 was released, so it appears that they updated the English FAQ to be more specific but forgot about the Deutsch version. :/ Maybe an email to their support address can answer the question (at which point you can self-answer to share with the rest of us!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked the author of the test about the missing songs and after checking again, he now changed the number to five. It seems that in an older version of the import tool there were more songs missing, but in the current version all songs from the original Rocksmith disc can be imported, except for:

> - Eric Clapton - Run Back to Your Side
> - Cream - Sunshine of Your Love
> - Seth Chapla - Star Spangled Banner
> - Seth Chapla - Jules
> - Chris Lee - Boss

While this information is confirmed for the German version, I cannot guaranteed that there are no differences in other countries, but the list of missing song goes in accordance with [the English FAQ of Rocksmith 2014](http://rocksmith.ubi.com/rocksmith/en-US/faq/), that says that...

> ..."you will be able to import 52 of the original songs into the new Rocksmith 2014 Edition [...] except Eric Clapton "Run Back To Your Side" and Cream "Sunshine of Your Love" from the main disc tracks, plus 3 of the 5 unlockable bonus songs."

To import the songs from the Rocksmith disc, you need to have a save file of the original game on your hard drive. When first starting Rocksmith 2014, you will be asked if you have played Rocksmith before, to which you must answer "yes". On Playstation 3 and Xbox 360 you will get access to the import tool in the ingame store under the tab "packs". It does not show up, if you answer the question with "no".

On PC, the import tool can be bought at any time from the Steam Store.

According to [the German Ubisoft support](https://support.ubi.com/de-DE/FAQ.aspx?platformid=38&brandid=934&productid=4285&faqid=kA030000000eblGCAQ) (last paragraph), if you answered with "no" on the Xbox 360 version, you can only get access to the import tool by moving the Rocksmith 2014 save file onto a USB or external hard drive. When starting the game without a save file on the hard drive, the question should appear again and you can download the import tool. After that, transfer your save files back.

Please note that in the Ubisoft support entry, this has only been confirmed for Xbox 360, although it is likely to work for the Playstation 3 as well. This question has not been answered on the English Ubisoft support forum, which is why the link leads to the German one.

Also, all DLC songs from the original Rocksmith can be used in Rocksmith 2014. For the PS3 you can download them from the PSN by searching for Add-Ons for the original Rocksmith. The DLC for the original Rocksmith does not show up in the Add-On list of Rocksmith 2014 in the Playstation Store, but after downloading and installing the songs, they are automatically recognized and added to your song list. You do not need the original Rocksmith to play any DLC songs in Rocksmith 2014. This is likely to work the same way on the Xbox and PC versions.